# Preprocessor directive with hash

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

```
#define f(g,g2) g##g2
main()
{
int var12=100;
printf("%d",f(var,12));
}
```

This code gives output 100, but if the preprocessor is implemented, `printf` will be rewritten as:

```
printf("%d",var##12);
```

Then, how the output came?

Comment: What do you mean by implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double hash `##` is a [*token pasting operator*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09dwwt6y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) of the preprocessor. The `printf` will be re-written like this:

```
printf("%d",var12); // No double-hash
```

> The double-number-sign or "token-pasting" operator (##), which is sometimes called the "merging" operator, is used in both object-like and function-like macros. It permits separate tokens to be joined into a single token and therefore cannot be the first or last token in the macro definition.

Comment: Is this "token-pasting" operator used only in macros definition or elsewhere too in a program?

Comment: @Ceres111 Token-pasting operator is defined by the preprocessor, so it is not valid outside macros. You can use it with both function-style and "object-like" macros, i.e. it's OK to write `#define MYVAR var##12` and then `printf("%d",MYVAR);`

Answer (score 1):

Because `f(var, 12)` is replaced with `var12`, which is the name of the variable you declared and assigned in the line above. The preprocessor directive `##` pastes together the two arguments.